# Angular.js: URL validation always returns 200

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I got a website (Angular.js based) with an online form where users may enter any URL. I would like to instantly check out of the browser, whether the entered domain is valid (=reachable, can be connected to).  I therefore only need the header information (status code), NOT the actual website content. I tried this piece of code, but it keeps returning code 200, no matter what the address is:

```
$scope.checkURL = function(index){  
        if($scope.items[index].address != ""){
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: $scope.items[index].address
                })
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config){    
                    if(status){
                        alert('yes!!'+status.toString()); //<--- always getting this!!!!    
                    }

                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                    if(status){
                        alert('error!!'+status.toString());    
                    }
            }); 
        }
    };
```

I am aware that I am running into CORS-issues here. I just wanted to ask if:

There is any way to reliably (!) perform this kind of URL-checking out of the browser (again, I just need header/status information, not any actual website content) - preferably using AngularJs.

Unless anyone tells me otherwise, I'd alternatively set up a REST-service on my node.js webserver that I query every time, although I wanted to keep that load away from my server. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure... But what's inside the `status` variable? If it's a 200 statuscode you have to compere it with 200.

Comment: I know. That's what I am doing. The question is: why do I always get code 200 as an answer, even for clearly non-existing urls (google.comnetorg)??